# Java URL Read Issue

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, flying-saucer

I am using [Flying Saucer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Saucer_%28library%29) to read contents of a JSP file from a servlet and generate a PDF. The domain is the same. It works on localhost but fails on server even thought the webapp has all privileges granted. I've tested by reading from different domain (works), reading in a generic url file without PDF (fails on server).

So I am not sure if it's a servlet or Tomcat configuration to enable the servlet to retrieve contents of a URL on the same domain?

Here is the timeout error:

```
org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:191)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:71)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.getXMLResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:211)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.loadDocument(ITextRenderer.java:134)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:138)
    com.cusa.sms.reportprinter.ReportPrinter.doGet(Unknown Source)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling like a massive idiot at the moment, but it's fixed. Server names are resolved internally as well and it's not guarantee that all hosts do that automatically for you. Just because I could see the page from my connection doesn't mean that the app could see the page from internal connection. So adding necessary host entries to /etc/hosts fixed all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

do you have the jars your using in webcontent. just including them in the project will not be enough, you actually need to drag the jars into webcontent, so that the servlets can have access to it.

Comment: I don't think it's the jars. I tried placing them in the lib folder where the app is and it doesn't help. Putting HTML to PDF aside for a second, I can't even read in contents of a URL using some generic code. It works if I get something from another domain but not on the same domain.

Comment: Ok, furthermore it seems to be isolated to Debian 5 and Tomcat 5.5. Playing around with turning of certain security settings with no help.